# Can we combine multiple html5 <video> streams into one .mp4 file?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, webrtc

I have two videos one for streaming my **webcam** and the other to share my desktop **screen/window**. I need to **combine these two media streams** into one so that I can **save it as an .mp4 file** and broadcast it over **WebRTC**.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to combine the two **VIDEO**(streams) tags by bounding them into a **DIV** tag.

```
       <div id="elementToShare">
         <video id="webcamVideo" controls loop autoplay class="webcam">No Support.</video>
         <video id="screenshareVideo" controls loop autoplay class="screenshare">No Support.</video>
       </div>
```

Then I used the **DIV** tag as a **canvas** to record the two videos as one using [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) library by [Muaz Khan](https://github.com/muaz-khan).

```
   var elementToShare = document.getElementById('elementToShare');
   var canvasRecorder = RecordRTC(elementToShare,{
      type : 'canvas',
      recorderType: CanvasRecorder
   });
```

But the **problem** with this approach was, I was unable to record the audio stream from my webcam with the canvas for which i used [ffmpeg_asm.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/ffmpeg). As the js file is **18mb** in size it ***takes a lot of time to load and process*** the video file.

As to my knowledge, WebRTC is still in its primary phase and I hope something efficient will come along to achieve such stuff.

**NOTE**: I was able to achieve the above functionality in **Google Chrome** only as at this stage Mozilla Firefox provided limited support. Whereas Safari has not provided [WebRTC support](http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc) so it was out of the picture from the beginning.

**EDIT 1** : Serving the above application with **Node.js** as server support has improved performance and video processing capabilities. For example : The ffmpeg_asm.js is unable to process video bit rate larger than 2200k without **Node.js**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to combine the streams in real-time?
If yes, you need an MCU which will merge these two streams into one stream and record this stream for you.

As an option you can record these streams on server-side and then mix the streams using ffmpeg.

Comment: Yes I am looking to combine these streams in real-time. I am confused on what an MCU is and how it would work. I am also planning on broadcasting these streams as a single stream so processing them on the server side may be an overhead.

Comment: I couldn't help myself. MCU stands for Marvel Cinematic Universe.

Comment: [Server Side Mixer for WebRTC streams](https://docs.flashphoner.com/display/WCS5EN/Stream+mixer) 

You can use a server-side real-time mixer with recording capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in a comment on another question that I just responded to with a complete proof-of-concept solution. Anyone that finds this - **a** solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71668398/8774425).

Note: The code there uses **video/webm** and the vp9 codec.. those lines can be easily replaced to generate a **video/mp4** file using h264 codec instead :)